How do I know which user runs a package in the Integration Services Catalog (SSISDB) from the SQL Server Agent?
I need to find out the user that runs the SSIS packages in the SSISDB but cannot find it. There are so many users and system users attached to the other databases that I cannot learn from that pattern which user is needed. I do not know by the name which one does it in the end.
How do I know which user runs a package in the Integration Services Catalog (SSISDB) from the SQL Server Agent?

You can read it in the Integration Services Catalog if you check the reports.
Since the deployed SSIS package runs from the SSISDB ("SSIS database") that is triggered by the SQL Server Agent, you can see the "Caller" in the report of the package executions.
The "Caller" is at the top right (red underlined):

And if you get a login error, this error message in the same report also has the caller in it:

MyPackageName:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
an OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Login failed for user 'AD\MyUser=the caller'.". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.".

